# Yii2 Use Primary Key from ActiveRecord model in the same function on create

Tags: activerecord, yii2, primary-key

I'm not sure if anyone else has come across this in Yii2 but when you have a table with auto-increment primary keys you don't need to include the primary key attribute value when calling ActiveRecord->save() on the object for the first time.

This is good as you can write your create functions quicker without having to do your check on the primary key and doing the increment yourself in PHP. The issue here though is when you try to use the primary key in same function ActiveRecord->save(); after the save has been called it will through an error saying it hasn't been set even though the row in the database has already been written.

E.g

```
public function actionCreate(){
     $model = new Object;
     $model->save();
     print_r(Object->findOne($model->primary_key_id))
}
```

I can get around this by just getting the most recent entry in the database and getting the primary key that way but it seems like the above should work. Is there another way to update the primary key in the ActiveRecord object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getPrimaryKey](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#getPrimaryKey()-detail)() function to get a value of a primary key. For example:

```
$model = new Object;
$model->save();
echo $model->getPrimaryKey(); // print primary key value
```